# Change macOS system-wide context menu feature "Search With Google" to "Search DuckDuckGo"?

Tags: macos

When selecting text, you can right click and select "Search DuckDuckGo ..." -- while your in Safari/Firefox at least, but for system wide apps it reverts to an un-changeable "Search With Google".

There a way to change this in the command line or a third party app?

Comment: If someone doesn't want to search with NSA's biggest competitor, he/she probably also doesn't want to use a browser controlled by the same entity!  Besides, they asked about the context menu, not the browser.

Comment: What are these "system wide apps". I can have "Search DuckDuckGo" in Notes, Microsoft Outlook, Safari itself etc.